# Duplicate rows and insert it below the selected rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to duplicate rows and insert it below the selected rows.

It prompts:

> run-time error 1004: this won't work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet

```vb
Sub InsertRows()
    Dim Ret As Range, Cl As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Ret = Application.InputBox("Please select the Rows", "Insert Rows", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="12345"

    If Not Ret Is Nothing Then Ret.EntireRow.Copy
    If Not Ret Is Nothing Then Ret.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="12345", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
 
End Sub
```

Comment: I understood what the problem is. One moment editing my answer

Answer (score 1):

`Ret.Insert Shift:=xlDown` should be `Ret.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown`. You are copying a row but not inserting a row. Also you can club it as shown below

```
If Not Ret Is Nothing Then
    With Ret.EntireRow
        .Copy
        DoEvents '<~~ Give excel time (If reqd by Excel) to copy and place it in clipboard
        .Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
End If
```

The above code will work for a normal range but if you want to copy and paste inside a table then try this

```
If Not Ret Is Nothing Then
    Ret.Offset(1).Insert
    Ret.EntireRow.Copy Ret.Offset(1)
End If
```

**In action**

[image]

Comment: Hi Siddharth, thank you for your suggestion.

Unfortunately after applying your code, the problem still persists.

The problem lies at **.Insert Shift:=xlDown**. It seems like the VBA doesn't allow the excel to add rows.

P.S. it is a protected sheet. I am not sure whether it will matter.

Comment: I have updated my post with a screenshot and a new piece of code. You may have to refresh the page to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the table doesn't have any filtered columns